# SIP load Testing via SIPP

Tags: sip, voip, rtp, sipp

I want to test load on a oracle acme packet SBC using Sipp tool. Sipp already installed on ubuntu 16.04 server. Need sample script for load testing.do we need to edit any .xml files?

Need to send INVITES and RTP via sipp tool. Remote server IP/port and sipp server ip/port details available.
I have tried below sample command but it did not worked properly

```
sipp -sf your_script.xml -i [local_ip] -p [local_port] -m [number_of_calls] -s [service] -l [concurrent_calls] -r [call_rate]
```

Comment: Please provide the xml file.
Could you elaborate on what is working not properly.

Comment: What xml file can we use for SIP and RTP load testing ?

Comment: see https://github.com/aparnaannapragada/sipp_xmls.

Comment: I have check basic test but it getting 503 service unavailable from the SBC side even correctly configure the agent. what may be the possible reason?

Comment: 503 is quite often used by SBC to indicate it fails to fulfill a valid request for internal reasons like maintenance, no more ressources (think audio DSP) and lack of licences.

Answer (score 0):

Try
./sipp -sf your_script.xml REMOTE_IP:PORT -i [local_ip] -p [local_port] -l [concurrent_calls] -r [call_rate]

Check this link below, it will help in your request about the xml file:
https://sipp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/int_scenarios.html
You can use UAC with media scenario (uac_pcap.xml).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).